# ThreeJS get outline shape (dupborder)

Tags: javascript, three.js, geometry

When I have a geometry, and I position my camera from top for example. I want to get the outline of the geometry as a new shape. So I can Extrude this shape. In the application Rhinoceros 5 this function is called: dupborder

I have found a lot of examples of outlining a Mesh, but that is not what I want.
A Convex Hull gets close to what I try to achieve but is not 100% accurate.

What I also tried is to get all vertices and faces and check if a vertice only has 2 or 3 faces. But some vertices have 4 faces and are also near the edge.

So what I try is to get a flat shape with the outline of a 3D mesh.

Comment: Just in case, what type of geometry of the model? Geometry, indexed buffer geometry, non-indexed buffer geometry.

Comment: This is a buffered geometry from the STLLoader

Comment: Does this model has "thickness" or it's not a solid body?

Comment: It is not a solid body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We finally managed to resolve the issue. We loop through all faces and check if an edge of the Face is only in 1 face. Therefor making it an Edge of the geometry.

Comment: Niels could you show the code example of this?